# Significance score of area under ROC curve

Tags: statistical-significance, bootstrap, roc, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I wish to perform a binary classification task on a dataset I have gathered, with unbalanced classes (~55% for one class).

The relation/correspondence between the features and the classes I deal with is not established in the literature yet, so a model which is not completely useless is of some value.

Since the data is unbalanced, I employ Area Under ROC (AUROC) as a measure of fit. I use random forest in order to fit the model given the data, so the AUROC it obtains depends on the partition to train\test data. Therefore, I believe some version of boosting should be applied.

I would like to test the hypothesis H0 = "The AUROC is equal to 0.5", and if rejected conclude that my model is better than random guess.

So, my question is: if I do 1000 iterations of training\test partitions, train a model on the training data and calculate its AUROC on the test data, what significance test should I use (on the 1000 obtained AUROC scores) in order to show that it is significantly greater than 0.5?

Currently I use [bootstraping](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~rgould/110as02/bshypothesis.pdf) to estimate the p-value, although I sure this is somewhat wrong (since the samples are not i.i.d.). I saw [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88007/statistics-for-area-under-the-roc-curve) and also [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/75050/in-r-how-to-compute-the-p-value-for-area-under-roc) suggesting significance testing for AUROC, but I am still not sure those how these tests work with boosting.

Any Idea?

Comment: maybe this helps= https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1f12/fce05a2bf0c247bc8e1180a369be6ccbecbc.pdf

Comment: I would have thought it isn't possible, but apparently you can do significance tests of Random Forests (at least, this is suggested by https://rdrr.io/cran/rfUtilities/man/rf.significance.html). Maybe you can figure out what that method does and then transfer it to AUROC?